# std::vector of type deduced from initializers before C++17 ... any workaround for C++11?

Tags: c++11

I learned that from C++17, with the deduction guides, template arguments of std::vector can be deduced e.g. from the initialization:

```
std::vector vec = { function_that_calculate_and_return_a_specifically_templated_type() }
```

However I do not have the luxury of C++17 in the machine where I want to compile and run the code now.

Is there any possible workaround for C++11? If more solutions exist, the best would be the one that keep the readability of the code.

At the moment the only idea that I have is to track the various cases along the code (luckily they should not be too many) and make some explicit typedef/using.

Any suggestion is very welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the answer by lubgr is a correct way, the following template is simpler and seems to work as well:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> make_vec(const std::initializer_list<T> &list)
{
    return std::vector<T>(list);
}

int main()
{
    auto v = make_vec({1,2,3});
    auto v2 = make_vec({std::string("s")});
    std::string s("t");
    auto v3 = make_vec({s});
    return v.size() + v2.size() + v3.size();
}
```

One advantage of using the initializer_list template directly are more clear error messages if you pass mixed types like in `make_vec({1,2,"x"});`, because the construction of the invalid initializer list now happens in non-templated code.

Comment: IMHO this is simpler and more readable, I would tag this as solution if experts do not find any special issue or corner case

Answer (score 5):

The usual way to use type deduction for class template when CTAD is not available is providing a `make_*` function template, e.g. for your case (trailing return type is necessary for C++11):

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <class ...Args>
auto make_vec(Args&&... args) ->
    std::vector<typename std::decay<typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Args...>>::type>::type>
{
   using First = typename std::decay<typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Args...>>::type>::type;

   return std::vector<First>{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

You can invoke the above with

```
const auto v = make_vec(1, 2, 3);
```

which gets at least kind of close to CTAD in the sense that you don't have to explicitly specify the vector instantiation.

Comment: After including <tuple> it works. However it works only if I pass temporaries, es.:
  auto vec = make_vec( std::string("s") );
while with:
  std::string s("s");
  auto vec = make_vec( s );
I get a loooong error printout, which maybe the most indicative line is:
  /usr/include/c++/6/bits/alloc_traits.h:395:39: error: forming pointer to reference type ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&’

Is it intended?

Comment: Good point, I fixed the answer to also work with lvalue references.

Comment: P.S. How can I format text in comments? Was I supposed to reply with a new answer rather than a comment?... I am new to stackoverflow....

Comment: No, comment is absolutely correct. You can put inline code snippets into backticks, like `this` is achieved via \`this\`.